# (Unusable) Virtual terminals?

Tags: linux, terminal, virtual-terminal

On many Linux installations, I have seen that Alt+Ctrl+F[1-6] will bring up a shell "outside" display/window manager, and Ctrl+Alt+F7 (sometimes F6) will  back the window manager / GUI. Combinations with the higher F keys (Alt+Ctrl+F[8,9..]) brings up a terminal with just a flashing cursor.
Are these virtual terminals too? What processes are running there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common setup in Linux is to have 6 virtual consoles, accessible by <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> ... <kbd>F6</kbd>, and subsequent F-keys switch to X servers, <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> to the first X server, <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd> to the 2nd if exists, and so on.

When you get a flashing cursor, that's a virtual terminal without any processes in it.
You can configure the number of active virtual consoles (with a login shell) you want to have somewhere under `/etc`, depending on your system. In Ubuntu, it's in `/etc/default/console-setup`. Many years ago, on very low-spec laptops I used to do this as an optimization to reduce processes and memory footprint as much as possible.

Comment: It's still a terminal, even if it doesn't have any processes using it yet.

Comment: @grawity So the other terminals (F1-F5) have login shells in them?

Comment: @kabZX: Yes, specifically they have `agetty` on them. Try `systemctl start getty@tty9` on a recent OS.

Comment: I used to install a utility (bastion I think) that put aggregated log output on F9. it was kind of handy.